# Passing arguments to launch file from Python API

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'd like to do the equivalent of

roslaunch a.launch foo:=bar

in Python. Right now I'm using the ROSLaunchRunner, but that's not important to me if there's another way to do this.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/237109/passing-arguments-to-launch-file-from-python-api/) by [juesato](https://answers.ros.org/users/27184/juesato/) on ROS Answers with karma: 43 on 2016-06-15

Post score: 3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

It's not well, documented, but the [roslaunch.core.Node](https://docs.ros.org/kinetic/api/roslaunch/html/roslaunch.core.Node-class.html) class supports all the same parameters that the `rosrun` and 'roslaunch' commands support.

So, if you were to launch a node with:

```
rosrun mypackage mynode.py _param1:=123 _param2:=abc
```

you could do the same thing from Python with:

```
import roslaunch

node = roslaunch.core.Node(
    package='mypackage',
    node_type='mynode.py',
    name='mynode',
    args='_param1:=123 _param2:=abc',
    output='screen')
launch = roslaunch.scriptapi.ROSLaunch()
launch.start()
process = launch.launch(node)
# do stuff
process.stop()
```

---

Originally posted by [Cerin](https://answers.ros.org/users/2186/cerin/) with karma: 940 on 2018-03-13

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 4

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [mugenzebra](https://answers.ros.org/users/20084/mugenzebra/) on 2019-03-11**:
this doesn't work with launch files.

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I've never had much luck digging into ROSLaunchRunner.... would it be okay if you run the roslaunch file as a subprocess of the Python script? You could use `os.system` or `subprocess.Popen` with the exact roslaunch command that you want run. I've done that quite a few times successfully.

---

Originally posted by [jarvisschultz](https://answers.ros.org/users/1272/jarvisschultz/) with karma: 9031 on 2016-06-16

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I found a hacky method that works at least in kinetic and possibly a few versions earlier- the [roslaunch api for lunar looks to support arguments properly](http://wiki.ros.org/roslaunch/API%20Usage#Roslaunch_file_with_command_line-style_arguments) so that ought to be used (and hopefully it gets backported).

(I also described this partially and probably confusingly in https://answers.ros.org/question/10493/programmatic-way-to-stop-roslaunch/)

```
import sys
...
# override the sys.argv in roslaunch with our own,
# make sure there are no blank '' entries
sys.argv = ['roslaunch', 'foo', 'bar.launch', 'arg1:=234', etc.]
import roslaunch
roslaunch.main()
```

([In the api](http://docs.ros.org/kinetic/api/roslaunch/html/index.html) it looks like roslaunch.main(argv) ought to work without the sys.argv overriding, but I think the call to main in `__init__` keeps that from working?)

It is then possible to put the above into a node and then launch that node like @cerin describes, and furthermore make the list of args set by args from the scriptapi call (though making that generic to any arbitrary arguments to arbitrary launch files is more work again).

Some similar questions:

[programmatic-way-to-stop-roslaunch](https://answers.ros.org/question/10493/programmatic-way-to-stop-roslaunch/) (already mentioned above)

[how-to-launch-a-launch-file-from-python-code](https://answers.ros.org/question/42849/how-to-launch-a-launch-file-from-python-code/)

[how-to-set-args-with-python-roslaunch](https://answers.ros.org/question/198910/how-to-set-args-with-python-roslaunch/)

[if-it-possible-to-launch-a-launch-file-from-python](https://answers.ros.org/question/263862/if-it-possible-to-launch-a-launch-file-from-python/)

[parameters-roslaunch-from-python-script](https://answers.ros.org/question/265796/parameters-roslaunch-from-python-script/)

Also programmatic rosrun questions:

[start-a-node-from-python-code-rospy-equivalence-rosrun-rosgui-qt](https://answers.ros.org/question/41848/start-a-node-from-python-code-rospy-equivalence-rosrun-rosgui-qt/)

TBD add some others

---

Originally posted by [lucasw](https://answers.ros.org/users/120/lucasw/) with karma: 8729 on 2018-06-19

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2